# Which Account does a QBO v3 API (IPP) Invoice or Sales Receipt's TxnTaxDetail touch?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Using the v3 QBO API (part of the Intuit Partner Platform), I'm querying an invoice that includes sales tax, expressed as follows:

```
"TxnTaxDetail": {
    "TxnTaxCodeRef": {
        "value": "3"
    }, 
    "TotalTax": 35.13, 
    "TaxLine": [
        {
            "DetailType": "TaxLineDetail", 
            "Amount": 35.13, 
            "TaxLineDetail": {
                "NetAmountTaxable": 395.87, 
                "TaxPercent": 8.875, 
                "TaxRateRef": {
                    "value": "4"
                }, 
                "PercentBased": true
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

When I run a balance sheet (using the web UI), I can clearly see which sale tax payable account the $35.15 hits, but I can't figure out how to access that information through the API **and I really want to**.

I try following the trail of business objects, hoping to find it that way, beginning with the TaxRate, which, when Querying Id 2, turns out to be:

```
{
    "RateValue": 8.875, 
    "AgencyRef": {
        "value": "2"
    }, 
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "Name": "NYC Sales Tax", 
    "SyncToken": "0", 
    "SpecialTaxType": "NONE", 
    "DisplayType": "ReadOnly", 
    "sparse": false, 
    "Active": true, 
    "MetaData": {
        "CreateTime": "2013-02-04T15:18:23-08:00", 
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2013-02-04T15:18:23-08:00"
    }, 
    "Id": "4", 
    "Description": "Sales Tax"
}
```

I gather that maybe AgencyRef has the answer to my question, so querying TaxAgency 2, I get:

```
{
    "SyncToken": "0", 
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "DisplayName": "New York State Taxes and Finance", 
    "TaxTrackedOnSales": true, 
    "TaxTrackedOnPurchases": false, 
    "sparse": false, 
    "Id": "2", 
    "MetaData": {
        "CreateTime": "2013-02-04T15:18:22-08:00", 
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2013-02-04T15:18:22-08:00"
    }
}
```

Now this is where I feel I'm at a dead end.

Taking a different tack, I looked at the TxnTaxDetail's TaxCode Ref, but I didn't find any help from TaxCode 3 either:

```
{
    "SyncToken": "0", 
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "TaxGroup": true, 
    "Name": "NYC Sales Tax", 
    "Taxable": true, 
    "PurchaseTaxRateList": {
        "TaxRateDetail": []
    }, 
    "sparse": false, 
    "Active": true, 
    "Description": "NYC Sales Tax", 
    "MetaData": {
        "CreateTime": "2013-02-04T15:18:22-08:00", 
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2013-02-04T15:18:22-08:00"
    }, 
    "Id": "3", 
    "SalesTaxRateList": {
        "TaxRateDetail": [
            {
                "TaxTypeApplicable": "TaxOnAmount", 
                "TaxRateRef": {
                    "name": "NYC Sales Tax", 
                    "value": "4"
                }, 
                "TaxOrder": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? **Is it really not possible to access through the API the information of which Account the sales tax portion of this transaction hits?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QBO Api posts Sales Tax to a default liability account based on this logic-

Transaction => TaxRate => TaxAgency => LiabilityAccount.
However, the api is not smart enough to provide you the details of this default sales tax account. We might have support for this in future.

Comment: So there's a 1-1 mapping between agencies and the liability account? I assume — given your answer — that the agency's DisplayName attr is for the agency, not the associated liability account.

Comment: Right. The liability account's name might differ from the agency's name although it is dependent on the agency.